# Selenium didn't find existing element

Tags: html, .net, selenium, c#-4.0, selenium-webdriver

i create app that runs selenium internet explorer webdriver.
the program work fine on my pc but when i trying it with the same driver on other pc
its throws exception on the first element saying that it can't find it.

- no frames in this html.

The first thing i checked is html pagesource the difference was:

on my pc:

```
<input name="cId" tabindex="1" id="CNum" type="text" size="13" maxlength="10" value="" autocomplete="off">
```

on other pc:

```
<INPUT tabIndex=2 id=CNum maxLength=10 size=13 name=cId autocomplete="off">
```

my selenium code:

```
driver.FindElement(By.Id("CNum")).SendKeys("123");
```

what can it be (the html source in other computer without type and in many cases without quotes.)

Thank you.

Comment: To my experience, IE is the most trouble-some browser to play with Selenium, it is possible that the IE version you are using is not supported by Selenium; I had this experience before, what I had to do is to downgrade IE to an older version and disable Windows updates. I recommend you to use Firefox or Chrome, they are much more stable than IE.

Comment: yes they are especially firefox but there is websites that works only with IE and that's where the problem comes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with

```
 driver.FindElement(By.name("cId")).SendKeys("123"); or
 driver.findelement(by.cssselector("input[name='cId']")).sendkeys("123");
```

Comment: i tried by Name, XPath CssSelector but still the same maybe the problem that the other pc html didn't have type="text" or IE settings ? (on my pc everything works great)

Comment: and one more thing with firefox driver everything works great in both pc.

Comment: Ya may be the IE version is not supporting the selenium jar files, IE has lot of issues, better use firefox and chrome fro the time being.

Comment: i checked the IE version on both the pc in the same last IE 11, same code, same driver ... maybe something in the IE settings or pc internet option...?